# React set variable in JS array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I've got a code

```
const importPost = (e, savedAttributes) => {
    await Promise.all( e.map( async (element, key) => {
        let product_id
        let productData = {
            name: element['Nazwa'],
            short_description: element['Krótki opis'],
            description: element['Opis'],
            backorders: element['Pozwalać na zamówienie oczekujące?'] == 0 ? 'yes' : 'no',
            sku: element['Sku'],
            slug: element['Slug'],
            type: e.length == 1 ? 'simple' : 'variable',
            parent_id: e.length == 1 ? null : product_id,
        }

        product_id = await Import(productData);
    }));
}
```

But in next iteration the variable product_id is not updated. How to fix it?

I've also tried to useState

```
const importPost = (e, savedAttributes) => {
    const [productID, setProductId] = useState(0)

    console.log(productID)

    useEffect(() => {
        e.map( async (element, key) => {
            let productData = {
                name: element['Nazwa'],
                short_description: element['Krótki opis'],
                description: element['Opis'],
                backorders: element['Pozwalać na zamówienie oczekujące?'] == 0 ? 'yes' : 'no',
                sku: element['Sku'],
                slug: element['Slug'],
                type: e.length == 1 ? 'simple' : 'variable',
                parent_id: e.length == 1 ? null : productID,
            }

            product_id = await Import(productData);
            setProductId(product_id)
        })
    }, [productID])
}
```

But it doesnt work at all. Even console.log prints nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `importPost` is a utils function or a  React component ? how you use it ? like this `import(asdsad)` or like this `<importPost />`

Comment: @somallg I'm using it like this import(asdsad)